# How do we justify differentiating under the integral for Poisson Integral

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral

Define $f(x,y)=(f*P_y)(x)$, where $P_y(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{y}{y^2+x^2}$, $y>0$ is the Poisson kernel. ($f$ is in $L^p$, for some $1\leq p\leq\infty$.)

In other words, $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\frac{y}{y^2+(x-t)^2}\,dt$.

I would want to prove $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}P_y(x-t)\,dt$, i.e. differentiate under the integral sign.

How do we justify the differentiation under integral sign? I know it has something to do with Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem, but I am having a hard time finding something to dominate the partial derivative.

My best try was to get $\begin{align*}
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|\frac{\partial}{\partial x}P_y(x-t)|\leq C/y^2
\end{align*}$ for some constant $C$ (using calculus computations). However, it seems that this is not good for satisfying Lebesgue's DCT.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have an $f$ in the integral, $Cy^{-2}\cdot\lvert f(t)\rvert$ is (for $y \geqslant \delta > 0$) a wonderful dominating function.

Comment: @DanielFischer How do we see that $Cy^{-2}|f(t)|$ is in $L^1$? We only have that $f\in L^p$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I thought $f\in L^1$. Without that, we need to keep a bit more. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One works locally, and finds dominating functions for $x$ and $y$ in specific ranges. We start by looking at the integrand

$$h(t,x,y) = f(t)\cdot \frac{y}{y^2 + (x-t)^2}$$

and its partial derivative

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(t,x,y) = f(t) \cdot \frac{1}{y^2 + (x-t)^2}\cdot \frac{2y(t-x)}{y^2+(x-t)^2}.$$

The last factor has modulus bounded by $1$ ($2\lvert ab\rvert \leqslant a^2 + b^2$), so we obtain the inequality

$$\biggl\lvert \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(t,x,y)\biggr\rvert \leqslant \frac{\lvert f(t)\rvert}{y^2 + (x-t)^2}.$$

Now we fix arbitrary $\delta > 0$ and $R > 0$, and note that for $y \geqslant \delta$ and $\lvert x\rvert \leqslant R$, we have

$$\biggl\lvert \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(t,x,y)\biggr\rvert \leqslant \frac{\lvert f(t)\rvert}{\delta^2 + (\max \{\lvert t\rvert - R, 0\})^2},$$

and the latter function belongs to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ since $\frac{1}{\delta^2 + (\max \{\lvert t\rvert - R, 0\})^2} \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

Since the regions $\{(x,y) : y \geqslant \delta \land \lvert x\rvert \leqslant R\}$ exhaust the upper half-plane, the Poisson integral can be differentiated (with respect to $x$, but the argument for $\partial/\partial y$ is similar) under the integral on the whole (open) upper half-plane.

Comment: Thanks! How do we see that "the latter function belongs to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$"?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\delta^2 + ((\lvert t\rvert -R)^+)^2} \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, hence that factor belongs to $L^q$ (where $q$ is the conjugate exponent to $p$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is very nice, but I was wishfully hoping for an easier answer, especially since later I would need to prove $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}P_y(x-t)\,dt$ (i.e. differentiating under integral twice).

Comment: Is there any chance I can use continuity of $P_y$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}P_y$ to justify differentiating under integral?

Comment: You need more than continuity to justify differentiation under the integral. Since the Poisson kernel is smooth, all derivatives of it are locally bounded (that is, bounded on all compact subsets of the upper half-plane), and thus it suffices to have sufficiently fast decay as $\lvert x\rvert \to \infty$. If you look at a couple of derivatives, you'll note that the decay becomes faster for higher-order derivatives, and thus up to constant factors, it turns out that the dominating function in this answer works for all derivatives.

Comment: Thus the Poisson integral is smooth (in the [open] upper half-plane), and you can differentiate under the integral arbitrarily often.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. If I want to read up more on Poisson integral, is there any resource/book that has it?

Comment: Uuhh, hmm. Any book on harmonic analysis should have lots about Poisson integrals. General analysis books often also have stuff. Rudin's _Real and Complex Analysis_ has lots of interesting stuff about Poisson integrals on disks. One can transfer more or less all of that to the half-plane, and generalise to balls or half-spaces of higher dimension (though you lose the huge help of complex analysis in dimensions other than $2$, but lots of things about harmonic functions remain valid in arbitrary dimension). If memory serves, Folland's book on analysis also has a good discussion.

Comment: And books on PDEs also tend to have a section or two on harmonic functions and Poisson integrals.

Comment: Sorry, just one more question, how do we know that if a function is in $L^1\cap L^\infty$, then it is in $L^q$?

Comment: I know how to do "interpolation": If $f$ belong to both $L^{p_1}$ and $L^{p_2}$, with $1\leq p_1<p_2<\infty$, then $f\in L^p$ for all $p_1\leq p\leq p_2$, but am unsure of the case $p_2=\infty$.

Comment: It's essentially the same argument. If $f\in L^{p_1}$, the set $A = \{ x : \lvert f(x)\rvert \geqslant 1\}$ has finite measure. Then for $p > p_1$ we have $$\int_X \lvert f(x)\rvert^p\,dx = \int_A \lvert f(x)\rvert^p\,dx + \int_{X\setminus A} \lvert f(x)\rvert^p\,dx \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_\infty\cdot \mu(A) + \int_{X\setminus A} \lvert f(x)\rvert^{p_1}\,dx \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_\infty\cdot\mu(A) + \lVert f\rVert_{p_1}^{p_1} < \infty.$$

Comment: One small question: Why is $(x-t)^2\geq(\max\{|t|-R,0\})^2$?

Comment: It's the other way round. But since the expression appears in the denominator, making it smaller makes the whole fraction larger. Make a case distinction. If $\lvert t\rvert \leqslant R$, then $(\max \{ \lvert t\rvert - R, 0\})^2 = 0^2 \leqslant (x-t)^2$. If $t > R$, then because $\lvert x\rvert \leqslant R$ we have $0 < \lvert t\rvert - R \leqslant t-x$, and consequently $(\max \{ \lvert t\rvert-R,0\})^2 = (\lvert t\rvert - R)^2 = (t-R)^2 \leqslant (t-x)^2 = (x-t)^2$. For $t < -R$, the argument is analogous, $0 < \lvert t\rvert - R = -(t+R) = \lvert t - (-R)\rvert \leqslant \lvert t-x\rvert$.

Comment: Hence $(\max \{ \lvert t\rvert - R, 0\})^2 \leqslant (x-t)^2$ for all $t$ (when $\lvert x\rvert \leqslant R$), and hence $$\frac{1}{\delta^2 + (x-t)^2} \leqslant \frac{1}{\delta^2 + (\max \{ \lvert t\rvert - R, 0\})^2}.$$